# SSL certificates download

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, python-requests

I am attempting to use requests package from python to access this site: https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do
When I ran this command:

```
requests.get('https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do')
```

I got the usual SSL error when your authentication verification fails..

Read through stackoverflow and adopted one of the solutions: download the certificate in (.crt) and then used openssl to convert to .pem file. I then copied the contents from this .pem file to the end of cacert.pem. However this did not work.

```
>>> requests.get('https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Sandra\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sandra\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sandra\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sandra\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sandra\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)
```

Any pointers as to how I can overcome this without resorting to `verify=False`

Also Is there any difference in downloading the file via https://superuser.com/a/97203 and https://superuser.com/a/176721?

Because I have no issue with `requests.get('https://www.google.com')`, do other websites place restrictions on the certificate you download?

Answer (score 1):

egov.usics.gov [does not provide](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=egov.uscis.gov) a complete chain in its SSL handshake.

[image: SSL Labs report indicating incomplete chain]

You'll need to employ a workaround similar to what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28667850/4483015)  until the site administrator fixes the certificate chain issue. The intermediate certificate in your case can be obtained from https://ssl-tools.net/certificates/yuox7i-symantec-class-3-secure-server-ca

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to setup CA cert:

- `$ pip install certifi` then
  `>>> requests.get(url, verify=certifi.where())`
- `>>> requests.get(url, verify='/path/to/cert_bundle_file')`
- `>>> os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = '/path/to/cert_bundle_file'`
  `>>> requests.get(url)`

Comment: None of the above works. My question now is am I downloading the certificate correctly: I am currently using this suggestion -> http://superuser.com/a/97203.