# Python SSL certificate verify error

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, openssl, python-requests

I'm using requests to access a RESTful API.  Everything seems to work.  I can authenticate, pull back a session token and even unit test the methods in my class I wrote for the API.  Then I tried to run my code.

First, here is the call I'm making.  The headers are static session-related items that get set in **init**().  The body is build dynamically from data in a file and passed in to this function.  All of the data is valid.

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=(Requestheader), data=json.dumps((Requestbody)))
```

When I run the code, it updates well over 100 records with the metadata I supply.  Somewhere around item 150 I get the following:

> ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate
>   chain (_ssl.c:1045)

My first step was to call the vendor and find out if ALL of their web servers had properly signed certs figuring they were load balancing me and I found a misconfigured server.  They tell me this is not the case.

Then I Googled the message and found that there is a verify kwarg, so I tried:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=Requestheader, data=json.dumps(Requestbody), verify=False)
```

I know this isn't ideal long-term, but I wanted to test it to see if The behavior is the same.  It did the same thing.  It ran for a while and threw the ssl error.  I thought the idea of verify=False is that it wouldn't check.

The vendor suggested I check the url I'm using, but it's fine.  I would think if there were a proxy server or real man-in-the-middle attack causing problems I wouldn't see success so many times before a failure.  I thought maybe it is a session timeout, but that should throw a 401 status and my activity level is too high for an inactivity timeout.

I'm a python noob and not a security professional.  Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Which version of `requests`? You should try to add more debug or capture the traffic to see each certificate you get, and see what changes. `verify=False` is in all cases not something that should be kept.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So the issue might have three resolutions as I see it:

1. A certificate is OK and there is something wrong with the code. The issue may occur, for example, while using prepared requests as described in [this solution](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests)

   But  I don't really think it is your case because in the snippet you've provided no such methods are used. For the two next variants, you'll need to get the URL that causes an error and explore it's certificate (can be done via browser).
2. A certificate is OK but a certificate authority that signed it is not included in CA list that is utilized by requests library. After you'll open a troubling URL, check CA in it and see if it's dates are valid and it is included in [this](https://certifiio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) list. If not, add CA in the trusted list for the requests library -- as explained in the answers to this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30405867/104746).
3. A certificate is not valid or self-singed. Same solution as in 2.

The general solution is to wrap your script in the `try except` clause and to print out all the URLs that will result in mistakes. Then try to request them one by one via requests library and see if the issue occurs. If it does, it's (2) or (3) case. If not — try to run script on another machine with fresh installed python and requests. If the run will be successful — then there's some issue in your configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive response.  I learned a few things. 1) I should be using sessions since I call a number of APIs at the site 2) It made me look again at the cert chain and it looks like there are two paths.  On the second path there is a self-signed cert.  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.riscnetworks.com  I'm going to look at your first link again on how to add the trust.

Answer (score 66):

## Update

`python-certifi-win32` is not maintained anymore as pointed out in the comment.

Use the drop-in library `pip-system-certs` instead.

```
pip install pip-system-certs
```

---

**OBSOLETE**

If you are using Windows and you have already imported the CA in the trusted DB store, you can install the package python-certifi-win32 that automagically will use the same certificates from the Trusted DB store.

```
pip install python-certifi-win32
```

Then your code should start to work

See:
[Python Requests with wincertstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422136/python-requests-with-wincertstore)

https://gitlab.com/alelec/python-certifi-win32

Comment: Unfortunately `python-certifi-win32` seems to be out-of-maintenance. Andrew Leech, the original author, [suggests to move on](https://gitlab.com/alelec/python-certifi-win32/-/issues/14#note_876668521) to his other project [pip-system-certs](https://gitlab.com/alelec/pip-system-certs). Drop-in replacing the library with `pip-system-certs` ([PyPI link](https://pypi.org/project/pip-system-certs/)) seems to work flawlessly.

Comment: `pip install pip-system-certs` worked for me => I would kindly suggest to update the post to make it more clear

Answer (score 39):

I have found this over [here](https://community.netapp.com/t5/Software-Development-Kit-SDK-and-API-Discussions/Python-How-to-disable-SSL-certificate-verification/td-p/113697)

I found this solution, insert this code at the beginning of your source file:

```
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    # Legacy Python that doesn't verify HTTPS certificates by default
    pass
else:
    # Handle target environment that doesn't support HTTPS verification
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```

Comment: This is not advisable.  requests has a verify=False option that can turn off SSL verification.   However, that means that you are no longer checking that the machine you are talking with is the one you want to talk with.  It leaves you open to a man in the middle attack.    My final workaround was to add a retry decorator on all of my functions calling the vendor API.

Comment: Since I was inside docker talking from one container to another and didn't wanna go into adding a CA myself valid on both containers, this was exactly the solution.

Answer (score 12):

For me it was sufficient just to add `verify=False` to the request:

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
```

Hopefully this very easy answer helps anybody.

Comment: Tkx bro. It solves for me too.

Comment: This means that the SSL certificate of the HTTPS server being accessed will not be checked, and any HTTPS server (even a malicious one) could present a self-signed or invalid SSL certificate without the client being warned.

Answer (score 10):

For Debian:

Download certificate

> openssl s_client -showcerts -connect SERVER:443
> </dev/null 2>/dev/null | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END
> CERTIFICATE/ p' > git-mycompany-com.pem

Install

> pip install certifi

Execute python

> Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44)  [GCC 8.3.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> **import certifi**

> **certifi.where()**
> '/home/user/detectaEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem'

> **exit()**

Execute command for add perm to python

> cat git-mycompany-com.pem | tee -a
> /home/user/detectaEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem

It has worked perfectly for me

Comment: This is the right way. I have verified it with mitmproxy and conda Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the resource URL as a trusted host by executing the below command:

In this case i have installed the package jupyterlab

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org jupyterlab
```