# I'm getting error when installing beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
C:\Users\esin>pip install beautifulsoup4
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/beautifulsoup4/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/beautifulsoup4/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/beautifulsoup4/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/beautifulsoup4/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/beautifulsoup4/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/beautifulsoup4/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement beautifulsoup4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for beautifulsoup4
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python SSL certificate verify error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390968/python-ssl-certificate-verify-error)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install bs4
```

or

```
python -m pip install bs4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org bs4
```

Comment: Please include why you think this is the correct answer, rather than just including a line of command. A bit of explanation would make things so much comprehensible.