# How to import from tensorflow.keras layers? Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to Python and have really a hard time to get work even simple tutorial code. If that continues like this I will switch back to R, but thats another story...

I am trying a tensorflow tutorial using PyCharm:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression

I tried this code. This code should work as it from the tensorflow website:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


print(tf.__version__)

dataset_path = keras.utils.get_file("auto-mpg.data", "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data")
```

I get this error message:

```
/Users/user/PycharmProjects/bintest/venv/bin/python /Users/user/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2019.1/scratches/tensorflow_firsttest.py
1.13.1
Downloading data from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1392, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/bintest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 248, in get_file
    urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2019.1/scratches/tensorflow_firsttest.py", line 8, in <module>
    dataset_path = keras.utils.get_file("auto-mpg.data", "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data")
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/bintest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 250, in get_file
    raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

What can I do to make the code work?
What am I doing wrong? Why even sample code never works (from different sources)?

Comment: Looks like you are behind some sort of firewall that blocks ssl.

Comment: Your code works without errors for me.

Comment: Ok, thanks that's a good hint!

Comment: By Googling the key parts of the error message you can easily find some possible solutions to your problem, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390968/python-ssl-certificate-verify-error)