# How to get ca certificates for python requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, ssl-certificate, cacerts

I am trying to run a python script that connects to myhost.comapny.com:8443 but it is giving SSL certificate error while running

```
 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)')))
```

My code is as follow:

```
import requests

url = "https://myhost.comapny.com:8443/environments/test/deplpyments"

payload={}
files=[
  ('request',('test.yaml',open('test.yaml','rb'),'application/octet-stream'))
]
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'Authorization': 'token'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files,verify="/user/test/company.cert")

print(response.text)
```

I have added certificate as :

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect myhost.comapny.com:8443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text >company.cert
```

But still it is not working and same error is coming as SSL verification failure. It seems that I am not generating certificate correctly.Can someone point me how can i do that correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python SSL certificate verify error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390968/python-ssl-certificate-verify-error)

Comment: No.I am more interested to know how to generate certificated that i can supply to requests?It seems I am generating it wrong.My code is fine,it does not have any problem.

Comment: Why do you need to generate a certificate at all? Certificates are generated by site owners, not the client that makes requests from a site.

Comment: we need to add trusted certificate at client side while making call to server right?In java i add using keytool in caerts as above mentioned way. In python either i can add using pip, that i dont wana try because of some restrictions.So manually i am trying to put certifcate in request as it is allowed by python

Comment: i resolved it by using : openssl s_client -showcerts -connect  myhost.comapny.com:8443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null > company.ca

Comment: So it sounds like the initial problem is actually with your system/OS, not with Python, and you just needed to install the certs.

Comment: yeah.i was putting them in wrong way as i mentioned earlier in question

Comment: Feel free to post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct command to import cacerts using python that worked for me is :

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect myhost.comapny.com:8443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null > company.ca
```

Then i supplied "company.ca" path, to the requests as a parameter to specify cacaert location.

Answer (score 0):

Are your required to verify the certificate?  If not, you can try to set "verify=False".

Comment: yes i need to do that else my post does not work properly. I tried switching off ssl in groovy/unix and in python also.My request does not go through.