# Python post request with certificate from windows certificate store

Tags: python, python-requests, certificate, postman

Is there a way in Python to make a post request, which apply the already installed .p12 certificate from the Windows Certificate Store?

I am looking for a solution similar to X509CertificateCollection package for C#, which enables the script to select the installed certificate by serial number.

I have generated a successful post call with Postman, so i know the headers and payload is correct. However, in Python i get an Authentication Error, as the exported Python code snippet from Postman, does not include the certificate.

I tried this solution unsuccesfully (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57053415):

```
import requests


response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, verify=True)
```