# How do I run Flask application Web server gives ssl error

Tags: python, ssl, flask, https, webserver

### I am running a basic web server with a Flask application over HTTPS, call it https://myappserver:5000 Everything works fine until I need to make a call to an external API, alpha vantage. As soon as I request the data with something like data = ti.get_sma(symbol=symbol, interval='daily', time_period=60) I get an error that looks like this:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in 
  full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in 
  dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "myflask.py", line 18, in add_numbers
    data = get_data(a, hashvalue)
  File "/opt/app/Get_Data.py", line 15, in get_data
    sma60, _ = ti.get_sma(symbol=symbol, interval='daily', time_period=60)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alpha_vantage/alphavantage.py", 
  line 175, in _format_wrapper
    self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alpha_vantage/alphavantage.py", 
  line 160, in _call_wrapper
    return self._handle_api_call(url), data_key, meta_data_key
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alpha_vantage/alphavantage.py", 
  line 76, in _retry_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alpha_vantage/alphavantage.py", 
  line 268, in _handle_api_call
    response = requests.get(url, proxies=self.proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in 
  request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, 
  in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 640, 
  in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 218, 
  in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, 
  in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, 
  in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
  SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.alphavantage.co', port=443): Max 
  retries exceeded with url: /query?function
  =SMA&symbol=DATA&interval=daily&time_period=60&series_type=close&apikey=<API key> (Caused by SSLError(SSLErr
or("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
209.249.175.115 - - [27/Sep/2018 17:11:56] "GET /_add_numbers?a=DATA HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

### Can someone please shed some light on what I would be doing wrong in this situation? If my web server is running on HTTP then this whole process works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: What is your exact Python version?

Comment: Hi Klauss, It's Python27

Comment: I need the exact version with all three numbers.

Comment: Hi Klaus, it's 2.7.13

Comment: Have you tried solution from following link, its kind similar error :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208466/sslerrorbad-handshake-when-trying-to-access-resources-custom-certificates-an

Comment: It is similar, but it doesn't look like there has been a resolution.  do I need to pass my certicate and key when I make a request to an external API URL?