# Certificate verify failing when running python under supervisord

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate, supervisord

I have a program that runs successfully in my user/virtualenv. The program access an API using `requests`. For the purposes of this post, the whole program can be read as:

```
requests.get("https://example.com")
```

This works totally fine when I call it from the command line. However I'm trying to get it to run under `supervisord` and for whatever reason when I do it this way it is failing with an SSL Error like the below:

```
SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)")
```

It is using the same user, python environment, directory etc. Any idea what else to check / what else could be causing this?

**Edit: I think this might be a firewall rule type of thing. Exploring that option.**

Comment: Did you try to add `verify=False` to your request: `requests.get("https://example.com", verify=False)`?

Comment: Yeah, if I add `verify=False` I get a different error (oddly a `502` from the server despite it always returning a `200` when run normally. Also, I don't want to add `verify=False` as a long term solution even if it did work since I do want to verify the cert.

Comment: Did you try to downgrade `requests` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667684/python-requests-getting-sslerror/44509839#44509839)?

Comment: I've not done that, but I think it's kind of missing the point of the question - which is why is this behaving differently when run under supervisor? So any workaround that involves hacking around requests seems to not address the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are the SSL certificates available in the supervisord environment? I assume you use requests.certs, so are the certificates there where expected `requests.certs.where()`?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this was a network proxy thing. The machine I was running on uses a squid proxy and I had to add the following line to set the right environment variables in my supervisor config for it to work:

```
environment=http_proxy=http://proxy.server:3128/,https_proxy=http://proxy.server:3128/
```