# Python certificate verify failed

Tags: python, certificate

The bellow code fails with "certificate verify failed" error. Earlier, it used to work.
Any idea why it fails? (I have certifi==2020.6.20)

```
import requests

url = 'https://net.cib.hu/ebroker/arfolyamok/cib_alapok_arfolyam/index?defaultLanguage=hungarian'
content = requests.get(url).text
```

Comment: did you change network status by any chance? I believe the certificate is referring to ssl which certifies the authenticity of a webpage. If its accessible through http try that instead of https.

Comment: No, it is only available through https.

Comment: can you access it through browser?

Comment: Yes, it works through Firefox.

Comment: If the certificate is not trusted, you may be experiencing the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12864892/6032132)

Comment: Both Firefox and Opera report the connetion secure, and the certificate verified...

Comment: According to [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=net.cib.hu), the certificate's chain is incomplete.

I found a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56633991/6032132)